# GitHub flavored markdown with an {% include ... %} code block

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have a GitHub pages site running Jekyll. I want to write a code block in a blog post, with the following content:

```
{% include file.html %}
```

Unfortunately Jekyll is reading this literally and including the referenced files content, i.e. the content of `file.html`. How do I explicitly tell Jekyll that this line should not be executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `raw` tag.

```
{% raw %}{% include file.html %}{% endraw %}
```